# Capitalize first letter of words in sentence, except on manual replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field that the user will fill in and I want to automatically capitalize the first letter of each word as they're typing. However, if they manually delete a capital letter and replace it with a lower case, I want that to remain (basically capitalizing the letters is what we recommend, but not required). I'm having trouble implementing something that will leave the letters they manually typed alone and not change them.

Here is the code I have along with a [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nB4cj/1/) to it.

```
<input class="capitalize" />
```

and JS:

```
lastClick = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".capitalize").keyup(function() {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        if (!(lastClick == 8 || lastClick == 46)) {
                //checks if last click was delete or backspace
            str = $(this).val();  
                        //Replace first letter of each word with upper-case version.
            $(this).val(str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}));               
        }
        lastClick = key;
    });
});
```

I haven't allowed for preserving the user's manual corrections, but as it is you can see in the jsfiddle that the input jumps around and doesn't work correctly. Can anyone help me or recommend a best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: In your code `event` is `undefined`:

`$(".capitalize").keyup(function(event) {` http://jsfiddle.net/j3nGm/

Comment: That's not the issue - I've logged to console and it correctly registers the key #. The issue is the actual implementation unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for good question and being well worded.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last;

    $(".capitalize").on('keyup', function(event) {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which,
            pos = this.value.length,
            value = this.value;

        if (pos == 1 || last == 32 && (last !== 8 || last !== 46)) {
            this.value = value.substring(0, pos - 1) +
                         value.substring(pos - 1).toUpperCase();
        }

        last = key;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tsUnH/1

Comment: thank you..but this seems not capitalize at all, or sometimes only the 2nd letter of the word.

Comment: Chrome! that's really weird.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't handle typing very fast (as you can imagine).

Comment: I have a suspicion this won't work (as in, working the end of the value), since it's somewhat dependent on the speed of typing being slower than the modification speed (which is not hard to do). I wonder, then if it would be more appropriate to use a `contenteditable` and wrap the characters with markup, with a class method or whatnot marking those positions that should not be uppercased. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".capitalize")
    .keyup(function(event) {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        // store the key which was just pressed
        $(this).data('last-key', key);
    })
    .keypress(function(event) {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        var lastKey = $(this).data('last-key') ? $(this).data('last-key') : 0;  // we store the previous action
        var $this = $(this); // local reference to the text input
        var str = $this.val(); // local copy of what our value is
        var pos = str.length;
        if(null !== String.fromCharCode(event.which).match(/[a-z]/g)) {
            if ((pos == 0 || str.substr(pos - 1) == " ") && (!(lastKey == 8 || lastKey == 46))) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $this.val($this.val() + String.fromCharCode(event.which).toUpperCase());
            }
        }
        // store the key which was just pressed
        $(this).data('last-key', key);
    });

});
```

I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nB4cj/4/ which will show this working.